# $\mathbb{R}^{n} / \mathbb{Z}^{n} \cong S^{1} \times \dots \times S^{1}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Today I've found something really interesting to me. Consider $\mathbb{R} / \mathbb{Z}$. It's not hard to see that this quotient group is isomorphic to $S^{1}$. But can we upgrade this for more dimensions?

Comment: Yes, with the obvious isomorphism.

Comment: Take the cartesian product of the exponential map (that induces the isomorphism in the one dimensional case) with itself $n$-times.

Comment: $\mathbb{R}^n / \mathbb{Z}^n \cong ( \mathbb{R} / \mathbb{Z} )^n$.

Comment: More generally, $(G/H)^n\cong G^n/H^n$.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews interesting , how can we show it ?

Comment: It is the classical definition of an $n-$ torus

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the map $f\colon\mathbb{R}^n\longrightarrow(\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z})^n$ defined by $f(x_1,\ldots,x_n)=(x_1+\mathbb{Z},\ldots,x_n+\mathbb{Z})$. It is a surjective homomorphism and $\ker f=\mathbb{Z}^n$. Therefore$$\mathbb{R}^n/\mathbb{Z}^n\simeq(\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z})^n\simeq(S^1)^n.$$